# Unique Constraint Violated in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, unique-constraint

I'm trying to add data into my SQL Database, and when I enter the following code:

```
INSERT INTO EMPLOYEES 
VALUES('100','STEVEN','King','sking@yahoo.com','PSEUDO',
to_date('17-JAN-87','dd-mm-yy'),'AD_VP',24000,0.45,90);
```

I get the following error:

```
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00001: unique constraint (ODEHat01.SYS_C00292486) Violated
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong, because when I describe my table(`desc employees;`), it shows that I have 10 fields, and I am trying to enter data into ten fields. Any help would be very much appreciated so I can enter the data into my employees table. Thank you.

Comment: You probably have an employee with ID as 100.

Comment: From a [random Google result](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/unique.php): *A unique constraint is a single field or combination of fields that uniquely defines a record. Some of the fields can contain null values as long as the combination of values is unique.*

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That means that the table has a unique index on one of its fields, and that you are trying to insert a value that already exists.

Very likely, the index is on the first column in the table, and there is already a row with a value of "100".